# What is -moz-use-text-color?

Tags: css, firefox, gecko

I understand it's deprecated in FireFox, and its replacement is currentColor.  My impression is that it's used for SVG-related stuff.  But what the heck is it? :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not really for SVG-related stuff.

It does the same as currentColor, e.g.:

```
a {
  color:purple;
  outline-color:-moz-use-text-color;
}
```

It was a mozilla specific CSS thing until it became standardized (CSS3)

Answer (score 6):

Just a follow up on this, it is deprecated, and the correct usage would be something more along the lines of:

```
.style {
    outline-color:currentColor;
}
```

Comment: -1 Seems to me that Infinity deserves the checkmark for answering your question.